# Can anyone tell me what the following [Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] error means, because when I run the program it runs normally

Tags: python, linux, series, neovim, pyright

Can anyone tell me what the following [Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] error means, because when I run the program it runs normally...

```
import pandas as pd

obj = pd.Series([4, 7, -5, 3])

obj.index = ['Bob', 'Steve', 'Jeff', 'Ryan']


 [Pyright reportGeneralTypeIssues] Cannot assign member "index" for type "Series" [E]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with your code

Comment: `Pyright` is Microsoft's static type checker.  It has made a mistake here.  You may ignore it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

reportGeneralTypeIssues [boolean or string, optional]: Generate or suppress diagnostics for general type inconsistencies, unsupported operations, argument/parameter mismatches, etc. This covers all of the basic type-checking rules not covered by other rules. It does not include syntax errors. The default value for this setting is "error".

```
# type: ignore

If you need to ignore this error
```